# What is the Plasma emissivity?

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics

I am wondering, what is the emissivity of super heated plasma that is of nuclear fusion temperature?

I know that it is the energy emitted from the surface of any material.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity

Is it the same as the emissivity as the Sun itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emissivity of the plasma is probably close to unity. Possibly your question is about emission instead. It will emit so-called black body radiation corresponding to a temperature of 100 million Kelvin. This spectrum peaks at 3-5 $k_BT$ or 30-50 keV, in the hard X-ray spectral region.

Comment: thank you, now what would it be for the following two: 30 million degrees k and 5778 k?

Comment: The peak frequency is proportional to the temperature, 9-15 keV and 1.8-3 eV, respectively. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Composition_and_power for a comparison of the solar and the 5778K black body spectrum.